# Adding some lines to Gradle dependenices gives me error

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to add dependencies for Navigation in android.

Before Adding any line in my file, it looks like:

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

}
```

I had to add this 2 lines in my dependecies.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

After adding those two lines and Resyncing I get Error:

"Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this error indicates that you have added the lines like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

While they should be added like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

compile is obsolete as of 'Android Gradle Plugin 4.1+'

Secondly, you can't add appcompat two times with different versions.

Depending on your build tools version you should change all the support libraries to use the same version so if you are targeting 'android 28' which is evident from what you already have add appcompat & the design library using these lines

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: yes it worked! But how did u got the idea of using alpha1?

Comment: and after removing that dependencies i am getting render error on  implementation 
         'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

Comment: All support libraries should use the same version, and seeing as how has appcompat was already implemented and working just fine, it meant that your build tools version was 28 and you were targeting 'android P', so I knew what version you should have used.
BTW alpha3 now is released.
What lines did you exactly remove and what do you mean by render error?

Comment: I understood the concept! But when I normally make a new project the appcompat is 

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
and it gives a render error(that makes all the textbox invisible).
but changing that line to

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
makes the whole project normal and good to run!

Recently I made a Navigation activity named Drawer.xml
and made header.xml as well.
The header.xml works fine,but drawer.xml now gives me render error again.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.
You get the error in the visual editor, right?
Can you share the error?

Comment: Sorry, but i just re-installed the whole android studio agian. And now everything seems fine!